# Trying to specify predict.coxph type within map2() function

Tags: r, predictive-models, survival, prediction, cox-model

Good day.  I recognize that this could be more appropriate for SO; however, I am including my statistical rationale on why I am choosing this method.  So, if there are any recommendations on a different approach, I would gladly hear them!  Thank you in advance for your time in helping me with this.

I’ve been scouring the web for the last few days looking at the documentation for map2. I have taken a training set, nested the data and created coxph models for it, saving those models in the nested table. Now I want to predict from that model, but I want to use a type=“expected" as, according to the documentation ([R documentation: predict.coxph](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/predict.coxph.html))

> The survival probability for a subject is equal to exp(-expected)

I’ve adapted the relevant code to reproduce my issues using the mpg data set.

I have 4 examples below that do not work after the predict function that does work.  Please note that I have removed the coxph.null models from this set, so the only models are of class(coxph).

```
#Needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(survival)
#Create data set
mpg_data <- mpg
mpg_data <- mpg_data %>% 
  mutate(mpg_diff = cty - hwy)
mpg_data <- mpg_data %>% 
  mutate(EVENT = (mpg_diff >= -8))
set.seed(1)
mpg_data <- mpg_data %>% 
  mutate(TIME_TO_EVENT = as.integer(runif(234, 1, 100)))
mpg_nested <- mpg_data %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  mutate(n_prot = length(model)) %>% 
  nest()
# Stepwise regression 
stepwise <- function(data) {
  response <- Surv(time = data$TIME_TO_EVENT, event = data$EVENT, type = "right") 
full <- "Surv(time = data$TIME_TO_EVENT, event = data$EVENT, type = 'right') ~ data$cyl+data$cty+data$hwy+data$displ"
x <- factor(as.factor(data$model))
full <- ifelse(nlevels(x) >= 2, paste(full, "as.character(data$model)", sep = "+"), full)
x <- factor(as.factor(data$trans))
full <- ifelse(nlevels(x) >= 2, paste(full, "as.character(data$trans)", sep = "+"), full)
x <- factor(as.factor(data$drv))
full <- ifelse(nlevels(x) >= 2, paste(full, "as.character(data$drv)", sep = "+"), full)
null_model_ONE <- coxph(response ~ 1, data=data)
full_model_ONE <- coxph(as.formula(full), data=data)
model_ONE <- step(null_model_ONE, scope=list(lower=null_model_ONE, upper=full_model_ONE))
}
survival_mpg <- mpg_nested %>%  
  mutate(model_fit = map(data, stepwise))
#Predicting values
#This works but is not type="expected"
survival_mpg_predict <- survival_mpg %>% 
  mutate(mpg_predict = map2(model_fit, data, predict))
##TRY 1##
predict.F <- function(model_fit, data){
  predict(model_fit, newdata=data, type="expected")
}
survival_mpg_predict <- survival_mpg %>% 
  mutate(mpg_predict = map2(model_fit, data, predict.F))
#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.
##Try 2##
survival_mpg_predict <- survival_mpg %>% 
  mutate(mpg_predict = map2(model_fit, data, predict(model_fit, newdata = data, type="expected")))
#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list".
##Try 3##
survival_mpg_predict <- survival_mpg %>% 
  mutate(mpg_predict = map2(model_fit, data, ~ predict(.x, newdata = .y, type="expected")))
#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.
##Try 4##
survival_mpg_predict <- survival_mpg %>% 
  mutate(mpg_predict = map2(model_fit, data, function(model_fit, data) predict(model_fit, newdata=data, type="expected")))
#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments.
```

Comment: Too much jargon and not enough stats. For example, if you force the reader to delve into R using non-statistical terms like coxph {survival}; R Documentation; Fit Proportional Hazards Regression Model; Description; 
Fits a Cox proportional hazards regression model, then any statistical merit to the question is lost, and you are in effect asking how to routinely use off the self software, which is out of scope for this web site, thus marked as `off-topic`. You will have to crouch this in statistical language to get an answer or post elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Other, more r-focused communities have said the code looks fine, but they don't know the survival model structure of type="expected" so don't know if that is correct code to use with map2 and potentially said that I may need a different analysis model.  So, I thought I would try here.  I will also post on SO to see if maybe someone there has an idea.

Comment: From what I see, R is pretty much the *lingua franca* of CV, with Python, SPSS and SAS trailing far behind. And Cox proportional hazards models are [not overly unheard of](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cox+proportional+hazards). I don't see closing this as off-topic based on these arguments alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get an answer from Stack Exchange and will share it here for this audience

Modifying ##TRY 1## to remove the newdata argument and change the map2() function to the map() function worked because I was trying to predict values on the same dataset.  map2() would have been appropriate if the test data set differed from the training data set.

```
predict.F <- function(model_fit, data){
predict(model_fit, type="expected")
}
survival_mpg_predict <- survival_mpg %>% 
mutate(mpg_predict = map(model_fit, predict.F))
```